# Undefined Method Scale In CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to use this code in my uploader

```
  version :thumb do
    process :scale => [50, 50]
  end
```

and I get an error saying

```
undefined method `scale' for #<#<Class:0x235b680>:0x0fb4c8>
```

I'm using Carrierwave with MiniMagick. How can I fix this error?

Comment: you find a solution? having the same issue

Answer (score 36):

Instead of calling scale call resize_to_fit

```
process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
```

<strike>or resize_to_fill if you dont want to keep aspect ratio</strike>

**EDIT**

My bad, both resize_to_fit and resize_to_fill are keeping the aspect ratio.

The difference is that resize_to_fit will keep whole image in given bounds, and resize_to_fill will fill whole given area so it can cut your image when necessary.

Comment: What if you don't want to preserve the aspect ratio?

Comment: like i wrote "resize_to_fill"

Comment: I also has to `gem install rmagick` and `include CarrierWave::RMagick` in my uploader class.

Comment: According to the documentation, resize_to_fill also keeps the aspect ratio: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#resize_to_fill

Answer (score 2):

The `scale` method is an example (generated by carrierwave in uploader) you need to use `RMagic` (or `minimagick`) functions (in their own gem, since smaller version of them is included in carrierwave) if you want to scale and therefor, not preserve the original image's ratio